# How to get tkinter canvas to dynamically resize to window width?

Tags: python, canvas, python-3.x, tkinter, autoresize

I need to get a canvas in tkinter to set its width to the width of the window, and then dynamically re-size the canvas when the user makes the window smaller/bigger.

Is there any way of doing this (easily)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I thought I would add in some extra code to expand on [@fredtantini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835732/3357935), as it doesn't deal with how to update the shape of widgets drawn on the `Canvas`.

To do this you need to use the `scale` method and tag all of the widgets. A complete example is below.

```
from Tkinter import *

# a subclass of Canvas for dealing with resizing of windows
class ResizingCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()

    def on_resize(self,event):
        # determine the ratio of old width/height to new width/height
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        # resize the canvas 
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        # rescale all the objects tagged with the "all" tag
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    myframe = Frame(root)
    myframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    mycanvas = ResizingCanvas(myframe,width=850, height=400, bg="red", highlightthickness=0)
    mycanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    # add some widgets to the canvas
    mycanvas.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)
    mycanvas.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))
    mycanvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

    # tag all of the drawn widgets
    mycanvas.addtag_all("all")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: A word of caution: using this with `grid` will kill your window manager!

Comment: And now: How do I get it to work if the Canvas is not the only widget? In my case, there is a Frame with button below the canvas which gets push out by the canvas...

Comment: This is excellent. I just want to stress the importance of `highlightthickness=0` when creating the ResizingCanvas, otherwise the canvas keeps expanding until you kill it.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it seems that all objects are rescaled except images added to the canvas with ```mycanvas.create_image(cur_image_width/2, cur_image_height/2, image=cur_image_bg)```. Do you know a way how to rescale the image with the self.scale function?

Comment: This solution is suboptimal as going through multiple resize event with an array of canvas, the canvas who originally had the same size will all have different size. Also, if you have a line or circle, the line thickness will not change.

Comment: Very nice except remove `bg="red",` which is distracting and makes the red line invisible.

Comment: This doesnot work for the image widget. If we try mycanvas.create_image, then it doesnot seem to work. Any solution for that?

Comment: Will crash if the original scale is 0: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101113

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `.pack` geometry manager:

```
self.c=Canvas(…)
self.c.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

should do the trick.
If your canvas is inside a frame, do the same for the frame:

```
self.r = root
self.f = Frame(self.r)
self.f.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
self.c = Canvas(…)
self.c.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

See [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111222645id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) for more info.

Edit: if you don't want a "full sized" canvas, you can bind your canvas to a function:

```
self.c.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

def resize(self, event):
    w,h = event.width-100, event.height-100
    self.c.config(width=w, height=h)
```

See [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111222645id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) again for events and bindings

Comment: can you use pack  inside another frame with grid?

Comment: @greendino if any of the frame's children use `pack` then all others will have to use `pack` too.

Answer (score 3):

This does it - in my version of Python at least. The canvas resizes both horizontally (sticky=E+W & rowconfigure) and vertically (sticky=N+S & columnconfigure). I've set the canvas background to a disgusting colour - but at least you can see when it works.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
canv=Canvas(root, width=600, height=400, bg='#f0f0c0')
canv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
root.mainloop()
```