# Resizing a matplotlib plot in a tkinter Toplevel

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have some code that opens a plot in a tkinter toplevel widget. When I grab the corner of the toplevel to resize it, I would like the plot to resize along with the window.

```
import Tkinter
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class grapher_gui(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.graph()

    def graph(self):
        x_vals = [0,3,10,15]
        y_vals = [232,120,45,23]

        toplevel = Tkinter.Toplevel(width=2000)
        figure = Figure(figsize=(10,5))
        ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
        plot = ax.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'k-')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time')
        ax.set_ylabel('Numbers')
        ax.set_title('Title')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=toplevel)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0)            
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, toplevel)
        toolbar.grid(row=1, sticky=Tkinter.W) 
        toolbar.update() 
        toplevel.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = grapher_gui(None)
    app.title('Grapher')
    app.mainloop()
```

The only thing I could think of to try was adding `sticky='NSEW'` to `canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0)`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [bind an event to the window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835289/how-to-get-tkinter-canvas-to-dynamically-resize-to-window-width) - in other words, instead of having the program watch for something like a mouse click and do something when it happens, have the program watch for the window being resized and do something when that happens.

In `graph()`, add:

```
self.toplevel.bind("<Configure>", resize)
```

Then make the variables instance variables (e.g. `self.toplevel` instead of `toplevel`) so you can refer to them from other methods.

Then add an instance method `def resize(event):` that does whatever you would need to do to redraw the plot with a new size. You can base the size off of the `Toplevel` window's dimensions by accessing `toplevel.winfo_height()` and `toplevel.winfo_width()` (add `self` if you've made that an instance variable).

When the `Toplevel` window is resized, that event will be "seen" and routed to the given callback (the method that's bound to that event).

Here's a small example that prints the size of the `root` window whenever you resize it:

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> def onsize(event):
...     print(root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height())
...
>>> root.bind("<Configure>", onsize)
```

By the way, [you only need to call `mainloop()` once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop-in-a-tkinter-application), in the `main` area. Don't call it for every `Toplevel` window.

Answer (score 9):

Try using `pack` with `expand=True` instead of `grid` with `sticky`. This simplified example works for me and the chart resizes with the window:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class My_GUI:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("Dashboard")
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.scatter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])
        canvas1=FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master)
        canvas1.show()
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)
        canvas1.pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)

root=tk.Tk()
gui=My_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I know it may be difficult depending on how far along your gui is to redesign using pack... but may be worthwhile instead of making a custom resize event handler. I do sympathize though, would be great if grid and sticky worked for the charts :/

Comment: Thank you for the easy solution! I always hate having to implement my own event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience if you use grid you need to use rowconfigure and columnconfigure on the parent widgets and then also the child widgets in order to make them resize properly.

```
import tkinter
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class grapher_gui(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        # Add col, row configure to the parent of toplevel
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent = parent
        self.graph()

    def graph(self):
        x_vals = [0,3,10,15]
        y_vals = [232,120,45,23]

        toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(width=2000)
        # Add col, row configure to the toplevel itself
        toplevel.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        toplevel.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        figure = Figure(figsize=(10,5))
        ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
        plot = ax.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'k-')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time')
        ax.set_ylabel('Numbers')
        ax.set_title('Title')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=toplevel)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0)            
        toplevel.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = grapher_gui(None)
    app.title('Grapher')
    app.mainloop()
```