# Python Tkinter Canvas shall fill Tk() window initially or when resized, but does not

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, resize, fullscreen

If this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
    class Program:
        def __init__(self):
            self.tk = Tk()
            self.tk.attributes("-topmost", 1)
            self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, height=500, width=500, highlightthickness=0)
            self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
            self.width = 500
            self.height = 500
            self.tk.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
            self.input = Entry(self.tk)
            self.input.pack(fill="x", expand=1)
            self.button = Button(self.tk, text="Start!", command=self.pressed)
            self.button.pack(fill="x", expand=1)
            self.pressed = 0
            self.start = time()
        def mainloop(self):
            while 1:
                self.canvas.delete("all")
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.width, self.height, fill="#4dffff", width=0)
                self.tk.update()
        def pressed(self):
            self.pressed = 1
        def resize(self, event):
            self.width = event.width
            self.height = event.height
Program().mainloop()
```

If I run it then this window opens:
[image: Initial Program]

If I then move the window it looks like this:
[image]

As soon as I resize it (by fullscreen for instance) I get this window:
[image]

How would I have to change the code to consistentely have the result where the canvas (I mean the colored part of it) covers the uncovered part of the Tk() window?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to resize canvas dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835289/how-to-get-tkinter-canvas-to-dynamically-resize-to-window-width).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get tkinter canvas to dynamically resize to window width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835289/how-to-get-tkinter-canvas-to-dynamically-resize-to-window-width)

Comment: why are you creating your own `mainloop`?

Comment: @BryanOakley How would I do it otherwise?

Comment: You simply call `self.tk.mainloop()`

Comment: @BryanOakley What exactly does it do?

Comment: That is perhaps the most fundamental question you can ask about tkinter. Start here perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8683217/7432

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of wrong and/or unnecessary code that is causing all sorts of problems. It boils down to the fact that you shouldn't be creating your own `mainloop`. Use the one that `Tkinter` provides unless you deeply understand why that is the case.

Start with this code before trying to do anything else:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import time

class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.attributes("-topmost", 1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, height=500, width=500, highlightthickness=0)
        self.input = Entry(self.tk)
        self.button = Button(self.tk, text="Start!", command=self.pressed)

        self.button.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", expand=0)
        self.input.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", expand=0)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

        self.pressed = 0
        self.start = time()

    def begin(self):
        self.tk.mainloop()

    def pressed(self):
        self.pressed = 1

Program().begin()
```

Comment: Do I add further code in the begin method or outside the class in this case and do you have to repeatedly (loop) type self.tk.mainloop()?

Comment: @RonLauterbach: that all depends on what "further code" you're talking about. In general I would say no, there doesn't need to be any more code in `begin`. No, you do not "have to repeatedly (loop) type self.tk.mainloop()`. Like it's name implies, it _is_ a loop already. You should call `mainloop` exactly once.