# How To Resize TKinker/Canvas to Fit Window

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
root = Tk()
myframe = Frame(root)
myframe.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
mycanvas = ResizingCanvas(myframe,width=50, height=25, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
mycanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

I used this bit of code to draw a canvas ( another method was used to draw lines)  coordinates range from 0, 100 xy.  I'm having trouble getting my Canvas to resize to fit the image im drawing.  I tried playing with the numbers with width, and height but I can never get the drawing to fill the screen.  Do I just need to play with numbers, or is there a way I can enlarge the drawing to fill the screen?  Also how would I go about rotating it?  I'm tried configuring the scrollregion, but it seems to have no affect.

Image for reference
https://i.stack.imgur.com/43hb4.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835289/how-to-get-tkinter-canvas-to-dynamically-resize-to-window-width

Comment: I tried that method already, it only resizes the drawing to the original intended ratio.  What I am trying to do is to resize the original drawing so that it matches the window.