# Tkinter resizablecanvas class does not resize all the widgets and it is malfunctioning. The canvas keeps on growing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Tkinter resizablecanvas class does not resize all the widgets and it is malfunctioning. The canvas keeps on growing. The Canvas keeps going in size. What I am trying to achieve is that I need all the widgets to be resized when I maximize the window. My code is as follows

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ResizingCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()

    def resize(self,event):
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)
        print (self.width, self.height)


class Test(Frame):
    def Widgets(self):
        self.tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.mainframe = Frame(self)
        self.tabcontrol.add(self.mainframe, text = "TAB-1")
        self.tabcontrol.pack(fill= "both", expand = YES)

        self.canvasframe = Frame(self.mainframe)
        self.canvasframe.grid(row=0, column = 0)

        self.canvas = ResizingCanvas(self.canvasframe)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column = 0)

        self.widgetframe = Frame(self.canvasframe)
        self.canvas.create_window(100,100, window = self.widgetframe)

        self.LABEL = Label(self.widgetframe, text = "LABEL-1")
        self.LABEL.grid(row=1, column= 1)

        self.BUTTON = Button(self.widgetframe, text = "BUTTON-1")
        self.BUTTON.grid(row=1, column= 2)

        self.widgetframe.update_idletasks()


    def __init__(self,initial):
        super(Test, self).__init__(initial)
        self.grid()
        self.Widgets()


root = Tk()
Software = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Could someone please help me ? Thank you !

Comment: When you configure the width and height (`self.config(width=..., height=...)`), you cause another `<Configure>` event, which changes the width and height, which causes another `<Configure>` event, and so on until the program crashes.

Comment: Removing the  (self.config(width=..., height=...)) line stops the program canvas from getting resized when the <configure> event is triggered. How can all the widgets be resized appropriately when the maximize button is clicked ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but for a first step you should probably learn how to use the `sticky` option when using `grid`, and learn about row and column weights.

Comment: If I click the maximize button, then the canvas size must get reconfigured according to the size of my laptop screen. Like it is given in the following example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835289/how-to-get-tkinter-canvas-to-dynamically-resize-to-window-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, what you want is for the canvas to fill the window even when the window resizes. Tkinter can do that automatically, if you use the proper `grid`, `pack`, or `place` options.

You've made this very difficult with your choice of using multiple layers of frames, and the use of `grid` instead of `pack`. If you're only putting one widget in another (the tab control in the root window, the canvas in the canvas frame, etc), using `pack` instead of `grid` will require fewer lines of code.

The following code illustrates how I would rewrite your code to eliminate some of the extra frames, and to force the notebook tab and the canvas to automatically grow with the root window. I've also added a color to the canvas so that it's easier to visualize.

Notice the use of `pack` instead of `grid` when adding `self` to the root window, and when adding the canvas to the frame. You can use `grid` if you wish, but it requires that you also configure rows and columns to have a non-zero weight. That's easy to do, but it takes three lines of code for `grid` and one line for `pack` when you have such a simple layout.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Test(Frame):
    def Widgets(self):
        self.tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.mainframe = Frame(self)
        self.tabcontrol.add(self.mainframe, text = "TAB-1")
        self.tabcontrol.pack(fill= "both", expand = YES)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.mainframe, background="bisque")
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.widgetframe = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window(100,100, window = self.widgetframe)

        self.LABEL = Label(self.widgetframe, text = "LABEL-1")
        self.LABEL.grid(row=1, column= 1)

        self.BUTTON = Button(self.widgetframe, text = "BUTTON-1")
        self.BUTTON.grid(row=1, column= 2)        

    def __init__(self,initial):
        super(Test, self).__init__(initial)
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.Widgets()


root = Tk()
Software = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```