# How to catch width and height after resizing the window of the program (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

(tkinter) I want to catch window width and height immediately after resizing. How could I do that, is any methods existing?

**Edited question:**

**deets,** It is not a duplicate. Because [in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835289/how-to-get-tkinter-canvas-to-dynamically-resize-to-window-width) there is canvas, and this method

```
self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)
```

is not working for Frame.  I still doesn't know how to resize frame so it would had the same width and height as the window after I resize it. (Like in photoshop, I resize the window and background is changing sizes).

**Bryan,** I tried to resize with  as you said, but it doesn't work. I tagged where I tried to do it with '!!!' comment. My code:

```
    from tkinter import *
import ctypes


class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, main):
        Frame.__init__(self, main)
        # Vars that will be defined by user:
        self.canvas_width = 600
        self.canvas_height = 600

        self.frame_width = 750
        self.frame_height = 600

        # Flexible widgets when window size alters:
        main.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


        # Canvas and frame
        self.canvas_frame = Frame(main, width=self.frame_width, height=self.frame_height, relief='groove')
        self.canvas_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.canvas_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.canvas_frame, width = self.canvas_width, height = self.canvas_height,
                        bg='bisque')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Right click menu
        self.rmenu = Menu(self.canvas_frame, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)
        self.rmenu.add_command(label='Add', command=self.hello)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", self.popup)

        # Bind
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.scroll_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.scroll_move)

        self.canvas_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize) # !!!!



    # resizing window:
    def on_resize(self, event): # !!!!
        # determine the ratio of old width/height to new width/height
        self.canvas_frame.width = event.width
        self.canvas_frame.height = event.height
        # resize the canvas
        self.canvas_frame.config(width=self.canvas_frame.width, height=self.canvas_frame.height)
        print(self.canvas_frame.width)  # return the same height and width
        print(self.canvas_frame.height) # after resizing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Tk()
    Main(main)
    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get tkinter canvas to dynamically resize to window width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835289/how-to-get-tkinter-canvas-to-dynamically-resize-to-window-width)

Comment: @deets Please see my edited question

Comment: _"I still doesn't know how to resize frame"_ - that's a completely different question from asking how to catch a resize event.